# AppleTV Gen2 will connect to unsecured wifi, but not WPA2

Tags: network, wifi, appletv

I have an old AppleTV Gen2 that's decided it doesn't like secured networks. I can connect just fine to an unsecured network, but the moment I enable WPA2 the appletv fails to connect with the infamous "There was a problem connecting to the network" error message and code (0).

It's like flipping a switch on and off. Same router, same SSID, same frequency, same band, everything in the same position in my apartment, the only difference is whether the network's secured or unsecured.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  After you made the change back to WPA2, did you reboot the ATV?  Also, are you sure you're trying to connect to WPA2 Personal and not Enterprise?

Comment: Yes and yes, I think it might be a byproduct of the ATV being both jailbroken and not having been updated in about 5 years.

Comment: Ok, you should’ve mentioned that it’s jailbroken in your question.  That alone could cause a problem.